# My sub documents are not saved when saving throught a parent

Tags: mongoose

I meet some issues tryng to save sub documents throught a parent document, followinng the official documentation.

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  Animals : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Animal' }],
});

var AnimalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});
```

I used to work like this:

```
function(User, callback) {
  var Animal = new AnimalSchema({ name: 'bob' });
  Animal.save(function() {
    User.Animals.push(Animal._id);
    User.save(callback);
  });
}
```

And everything worked great, but i have seen in the docthat we can just write:

```
function(User, callback) {
  var Animal = new AnimalSchema({ name: 'bob' });
  User.Animals.push(Animal);
  User.save(callback);
}
```

But it's not working 100% for me:

My sub document is nested into my document, but i can't `find()` it, it's part of the parent as a regular key.

Also, when i have another nested bloc, like:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  Animals : {
    dogs: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Animal' }],
    cats: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Animal' }]
  }
});
```

and i do:

```
function(User, callback) {
  var Animal = new AnimalSchema({ name: 'bob' });
  User.Animals.dogs.push(Animal);
  User.save(callback);
}
```

I just have an `ObjectId` as item in my `User.dogs` array (that i can't populate for the same reason than above).

Am i missing something ? I am using mongoose 3.8 and they say [in the doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) doc that we should able to query tu sub document this way.

`It is debatable that we really want two sets of pointers as they may get out of sync. Instead we could skip populating and directly find() the stories we are interested in.`